# ASP.NET Proxy Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

Let me try to explain what I need. I have a server that is visible from the internet. What I need is to create a ASP.NET application that get the request of a web Site and send to a internal server, then it gets the response and publish the the info. For the client this should be totally transparent.

For different reasons I cannot redirect the port to the internal server. What I can do but no know how - maybe the answer is there - is to create a new Web Site that its host in the other server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why won't any old proxy software work for this?  Why does it need to be an ASP.NET application?  There are TONS of tools out there (both Windows and *nix) that will get the job done quite easily.  Check [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or [NetProxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20090601113940/http://www.grok.co.uk:80/netproxy/) for starters.

If you need to integrate with IIS, [IISProxy](http://www.iisproxy.net/) looks like it would do the trick too.

Answer (score 1):

I use apache mod_proxy and mod_proxy_balancer. Works awesome running 5 domains a cluster of 4 web boxes.