# ASP.NET proxy to access protected resources (other webapps)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running an ASP.NET based CMS/portal site using mojoPortal (www.mojoportal.com, open source). Users log in and access content based on their group/role. Now I would like to add a different web application (a wiki, MediaWiki based for ease of maintenance, but essentially any other web application or site) that should only be accessible to certain roles within mojo.

A possible solution I figured out would be to hide the wiki completely from direct external access and proxy the requests through mojo, such that they are only accessible for the desired groups.

Having found this question: [aspnet-proxy-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460/asp-net-proxy-application), I am unsure whether a general proxy will do in this case. Is this the way to go or are there any easier solutions? I'd appreciate any thoughts or reading resources on how to implement this scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Forms Authentication you could move the ASP.NET files that run your protected widgets into their own directory. Then put a web.config in that directory that specifies the user roles that are allowed in that directory.

Comment: Justin, thanks. This would however mean that the sub-application is .NET also. I have no experience in nesting web.configs but have read of numerous problems (regarding DotNetNuke for this matter). I will investigate it, but would however prefer a transparent "proxy" in ASP.NET.